# websphere that supports jpa2.2

Tags: websphere, jpa-2.2

so i upgraded my application to use hibernate 5.4 that supports jpa 2.2
i used to use websphere 9 as my application server but unfortunately this server supports only jpa 2.0 and 2.1
i have tried to use 5.4 with jpa2.1 it works but i may cause problems in my application in the future.
so is there any version of websphere that supports jpa 2.2 ?

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: La valeur '2.2' de l'attribut 'version' de l'?l?ment 'persistence' n'est pas valide au regard de l'utilisation de l'attribut correspondant. L'attribut 'version' doit avoir la valeur fixe de '2.1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA 2.2 is part of the Java EE and Jakarta EE 8 specifications.  Traditional WebSphere Application Server 9 only supports JPA 2.0 and 2.1 because it supports up to Java EE 7.  WebSphere Liberty and Open Liberty support Java EE and Jakarta EE 8.  Since you are already using traditional WebSphere you have access to use WebSphere Liberty.

There are migration tooling that helps with transitioning from using traditional WebSphere to Liberty.  You can find information about the migration toolkit here:  https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/migration/

Comment: thanks for your quick response, one more question is there any possibility to deactivate the JPA validation in the traditional WebSphere 9.0 ?  so it stops throwing exceptions when jpa=2.2

Answer (score 0):

English version of the error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: The value '2.2' of the attribute 'version' of the element 'persistence' is not valid with regard to l use of the corresponding attribute. The 'version' attribute must have the fixed value of '2.1.

Is there a reason you need to run with your persistence.xml schema at a version of "2.2"?

The only reason to do this would be to gain access to a new part of the persistence.xml schema; added as part of the JPA 2.2 specification. If you aren't leveraging anything new, I would suggest staying with a version of "2.1".